# Is it possible to set the color scheme of SwipeRefreshLayout in XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, swiperefreshlayout

I'm working with [`SwipeRefreshLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html).

I know how to `setColorScheme` dynamically.

Is it possible to set the scheme color `attribute` of SwipeRefreshLayout in XML?

Comment: I ran into this problem also, did you find the answer?

Comment: @Pike D : Document does not have until now. But I think there is the way to do this, you use Data Binding with custom attribute, then link to @Binding method include code `setColorScheme`, should work.

Answer (score 2):

*This worked for me in 2021:*

Note: `setColorScheme` is deprecated now so use `setColorSchemeResources` instead.

I set up my own colors in the xml and using them like `swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(<color in xml>);`. Changing the color in the xml changes it everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible just set the setColorSchemesColors method

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE);
```